# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Tags: c#, string, list

This question has probably been answered hundreds of times, but here goes.

I have this chunck of code:

```
private void PopulateStringDropdownList(List<ObjectInfo> listObject,
                                        object selectedType = null)
{
    List<string> listString = listObject.OrderBy(x => x.m_Type).ToString();
    for (int i = 0; i < listString .Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < listString .Count; j++)
        { 
            if (String.Equals(listString [i], listString [j]))
            {
                listString.RemoveAt(j);
            }
        }
    }
    ViewBag.property1 = new SelectList(listString );
}
```

So basically I'm trying to populate a dropdown List with strings coming from a property of each objects contained in the list I pass in parameter.

But the code doesn't compile because of the error you're seeing up there, and I've yet to understand why exactly. Any help anyone?

Comment: Which line is failing? (And please take the time to format your code yourself for future questoins.)

Comment: Use ToList() instead of ToString().

Comment: _listString_ is never used. And are you trying to remove duplicate strings in _listObject_?

Comment: @HansPassant The same error shows if I use ToList().

Comment: @HervéSimard Where is the error?

Comment: @JonSkeet The first line if failing. Sorry for the formatting, I'm still trying to figure out how it works here ^^

Comment: @CédricBignon Sorry, I've written my code again so that it may be correct.

Comment: Come on folks.  He's got 11 reputation.  Let's allow him to acclimate himself to SO before downvoting :P.

Comment: @HervéSimard: "The same error shows if I use ToList()" - `ToList()` in that position returns a `List<ObjectInfo>`, not a `List<string>`. Hence, I assume the error message is not *exactly* the same. Please be precise about error messages.

Comment: @HervéSimard Do you really mean _listObject.RemoveAt(j)_ instead of _listString.RemoveAt(t)_?

Comment: Just to point out: @FishBasketGordo wrote something that helped me down below. :)

Comment: @CédricBignon Nope! nope! Corrected that one too. Hahaha, thanks for pointing out: in fact, I have just written a chunck of code that's not the "real" code, that's why there were so many "typos" around. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the problematic line:

```
List<string> listString = listObject.OrderBy(x => x.m_Type).ToString();
```

`ToString` returns a string, and you're trying to assign to a `List<string>` variable.

You need to do something like this:

```
List<string> listString = listObject.OrderBy(x => x.m_Type)
                                    .Select(x => x.ToString())
                                    .ToList();
```

This statement will order your `listObject` enumerable to the order that your want, then convert the values to strings, and finally convert the enumerable to a `List<string>`.

Answer (score 5):

Look at this code:

```
List<string> listString = listObject.OrderBy(x => x.m_Type).ToString();
```

The right hand side expression is calling `ToString()` on the result of `OrderBy` - which isn't useful itself, and will result in a `string`.

You're then trying to assign that `string` expression to a new variable of type `List<string>`. That's not going to work.

I *suspect* you just want `ToList` instead of `ToString`:

```
List<string> listString = listObject.OrderBy(x => x.m_Type).ToList();
```

Comment: It's not that I don't want to; rather, it doesn't work. I thought first that it was because the list that receives the data was a string list, but... nope.

Comment: @HervéSimard: What do you mean? What failed when you tried this? What's the type of the `m_Type` field? (Please be more specific in future.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `ToList` instead of `ToString`.

Also, if all you're trying to do is remove duplicates, you can simply use LINQ and do this:

```
List<string> listString = listObject.OrderBy(x => x.m_Type).
    Select(x => x.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Oh! Will try that one too.

Comment: listObject is a list of ObjectInfo, not string, so use listObject.OrderBy(x => x.m_Type).Select(l => l.ToString()).Distinct().ToList()

Comment: @AndyClaw Thanks Andy. Think I was editing my answer just as you commented.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify all your code into:

```
List<string> listString = listObject.OrderBy(x => x.m_Type)
                                    .Select(x => x.ToString())
                                    .Distinct()  // Remove duplicated entries
                                    .ToList();
ViewBag.property1 = new SelectList(listString);
```

Answer (score 2):

There was still a bit of correcting to be done. Here's the complete code:

```
private void PopulateStringDropdownList(List<ObjectInfo> listObjects, object selectedType = null)

        {
            List<string> listString = listObjects.OrderBy(x => x.m_Type)
                                             .Select(x => x.m_Type.ToString())
                                             //.Distinct()
                                             .ToList();
            ViewBag.cardType = new SelectList(listString );
        }
```

That way the correct value found is the string of the Type and not the type of the object.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Convert list of `int` to list of `string`:

```
List<string> listString =  listObject.OrderBy(x => x.m_Type).
Select(x =>x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string tags = Convert.ToString(item.tagsNcategory.OrderBy(x => x.meta_value.Select(x => x.ToString()))); 
var tags_name = tags.Replace(",", " ");
```

Comment: please add explanations.