# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<stings>'orchestrator function

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

i've seen this question on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654923/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-system-collections-generic-liststri) but my case is different:

This is the error message when im trying to return the list values:

[image]

but i think this needs a little bit more explanation on how the function is declared and what needs to be returned:

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")]//function1 or F1
    public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        //extract the key from the context param
        var key = context.GetInput<input_key>()?.Key;

        //This list include the I value i need to send to the api
        var incrementing_values_list = new List<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 0x10000; i += 0x100)
        {
            string incrementing_value = "0x" + i.ToString("x16");
            incrementing_values_list.Add(incrementing_value);
        }

        var parallelTasks = new List<Task<string>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < incrementing_values_list.Count; i++) //for each value in the list called incrementing_values_list. i'll send an api request
        {
            
            ("Function1_HelloTest", incrementing_values_list[i]);
            Task<string> task = context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", incrementing_values_list[i]);

            parallelTasks.Add(task);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"************** 'Waiting' for parallel results ********************");
        await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks);
        Console.WriteLine($"************** All activity functions complete ********************");

        parallelTasks.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i.Result));            


        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var completedParallelActivity in parallelTasks)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(completedParallelActivity.Result);
        }
        
        
        return sb.ToString(); //Here is where i get the error message

}
```

*Update:  tried returning the following and also get an error

```
string combindedString = string.Join(",", parallelTasks);
return combindedString;
```

[image]

What is the right way to return the list?

Comment: Take a step back and think about what you're doing for a moment. You've defined a method stating you want to return a collection of strings, and you're running a collection of tasks which each return a string, but then you're combining them into a single result. `StringBuilder` does what it says - it builds a single string. `string.Join`, again, returns a single string.  So, as you've made two attempts to return a single string, is your method's return type really what you want? Do you want `Task<string>` instead, or are you just not sure how to take the task results and turn them into a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to change the return type of your function. Both `sb.ToString()` and `string.Join(",", parallelTasks);` return a string. However, the return type of your function is `Task<List<string>>`

Can you change the return type of the function to `Task<string>`?
`public static async Task<string> RunOrchestrator( [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)`